# Flutter Navigator v2.0 how to pop a child nested route

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation

I've been trying flutter new declarative Navigator v2.0, following this 
[johnpryan](https://gist.github.com/johnpryan/bbca91e23bbb4d39247fa922533be7c9) [**example**](https://dartpad.dev/bbca91e23bbb4d39247fa922533be7c9?), I've decide to change **FlatButton** pop() in the **BookDetailsScreen**:

```
class BookDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
       children: [
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
               Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Back'),
              ),
          ],
}
```

To the parent router **AppBar()** in the **_AppShellState**:

```
class _AppShellState extends State<AppShell> {
  InnerRouterDelegate _routerDelegate;
  ChildBackButtonDispatcher _backButtonDispatcher;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = widget.appState;

    _backButtonDispatcher.takePriority();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appState.selectedBook != null
          ? AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () => _routerDelegate.popRoute(),
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                  onPressed: () => null,
                )
              ],
            )
          : AppBar(),
      body: Router(
        routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
        backButtonDispatcher: _backButtonDispatcher,
      ),
```

[Fullcode](https://dartpad.dev/8ee9b2c4fcfa59157998c46564968dbc?)

My question is, I'm using **_routerDelegate.popRoute()** it's working, but I not sure if it is right way to do it?

PS: If someone have a more complex example using Navigator v2.0, I'm new to Flutter and need to know best practices to how separate and organize my code, how to add more routes for instance an Edit and login screen? working with more objects like users, books, authors and etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a tweak to show the back button, kinda naturally, when the BookDetailsScreen is presented.

1. In the `_AppShellState` class

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ... 

    return Scaffold(
      // <- Comment out this appBar
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   leading: appState.selectedBook != null
      //       ? IconButton(
      //           icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      //           onPressed: () => _routerDelegate.popRoute(),
      //         )
      //       : null,
      // ),
      ...
      // Keep the rest part the same
      
    );
  }
```

2. Add the `appBar` property into Screens Scaffold in the `build` method, like this below. Have the appBar on both BooksListScreen and BookDetailsScreen,

```
class BooksListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(), // <- This is the key
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Nice effort but this does not answer the question.